# Getting the targetdir variable must be provided when invoking this installer while installing python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, window

I have Python 2.7 on my Window 7. Problem is with python 3.5 and 3.6 version only.

Comment: provide full control of target directory to the system user.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Hey just right click on exe file and run as a administrator.It worked for me :)

Comment: Unless you are not an administrator and this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2-3 ways to solve the issue:

1. As suggested above, Right-click on exe file and run as administrator.
2. Open command prompt in administrator mode. 
   Just take a note of where your setup file location is present. 
   Use `cd C:\Users\ABC\Downloads`

Type `C:\>python-3.7.0.exe TargetDir=C:\Python37`

*Note: my setup file was python-3.7.0.exe*
Follow the steps

3.Please try to do the custom installation and choose a clean folder location. In custom installation, we can tick or un-tick some option. Choose only 1/2 option which are required. Leave rest. Sometimes this troubleshoot step also help to install.

4.Go to properties of python Setup file. Go to advance setting and change the owner to administrator. Also go to compatibility and tick on "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Right Click on the setup file and **Run as administrator**

[image]