# Getting "targetdir variable must be provided when invoking this installer" message

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

when i try to install python i'm getting the "targetdir variable must be provided when invoking this installer" whilst attempting to install python 3.5. I have used  tried to [Run as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827889/getting-the-targetdir-variable-must-be-provided-when-invoking-this-installer-whi) however, I', still getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today and it did not work even with "run as administrator".
To solve the problem, I ran powershell as administrator and executed the following command:

```
python-3.6.1.exe InstallAllUsers=1 TargetDir="c:\python3.6"
```

Answer (score -1):

I met this issue also.
I find method to resolve it.
Right click the exe file and choose run as administrator.
Then it can go on installing and to be successful.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to install the latest python for windows python-3.7.0b4-amd64-webinstall but got the same error.
The problem was solved by the following steps:

- Open command prompt in administrator mode.
- Go to the location where the installer is downloaded.
- `C:\>cd C:\Users\XYZ\Downloads`
- `C:\>python-3.7.0b4-amd64-webinstall.exe TargetDir=C:\Python37`
  The installer will open and chose the default installer and click Install.